# Items in a horizontal StackPanel position incorrectly on remote device (Windows Store App)

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 for use with a specific kind of Surface Pro tablet.

While in the Designer, I lined up two TextBlocks exactly as I wanted them using a horizontal StackPanel and ran them in the Simulator (1920x1080) and they were aligned properly. When the same app was exported to the device (1920x1080), the text slanted downward, with each additional TextBlock bringing each TextBlock after it down by 2px.

How can I ensure that the items in the StackPanel don't move themselves downwards on my device? Thanks!

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,30,40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="867">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}"  Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="14,6,12,0" Text="&#xE097;" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="14,6,12,0" Text="&#xE097;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding C}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="14,6,12,0" Text="&#xE097;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: First, something unrelated, in the nested stackpanel you don't need to declare Grid.Column because it is not nested in a grid.
Secondly, I'd like to see the styles for your textblocks.
Thirdly, If nothing else works try using one textblock with several [Runs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run.aspx) in it

Comment: 1) Oops, didn't mean to copy that over. 2) The style is the same defined in  generic.xaml 3) I wasn't aware of the existence of Runs. Surely that has to be the best way to do this, that's probably the answer right there.

Comment: @Corcus Upon testing, the problem with Run is that I'm not able to properly vertically align the smaller symbols like I am with the stack panel. They don't align to the center of the text line by default and I don't have a Margin property to manually align them. Advice?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know of a way to align the Runs in a textblock. I believe that the idea of Runs is not to be manipulatable in terms of margin and padding as the textblock will do that for them. I'm sorry I couldn't help.